# Creating JSON data from string and using json.dumps

Tags: json, python-2.7, influxdb

I am trying to create JSON data to pass to InfluxDB. I create it using strings but I get errors. What am I doing wrong. I am using json.dumps as has been suggested in various posts.

Here is basic Python code:

```
json_body = "[{'points':["
json_body += "['appx', 1, 10, 0]"
json_body += "], 'name': 'WS1', 'columns': ['RName', 'RIn', 'SIn', 'OIn']}]"

print("Write points: {0}".format(json_body))
client.write_points(json.dumps(json_body))
```

The output I get is

```
Write points: [{'points':[['appx', 1, 10, 0]], 'name': 'WS1', 'columns': ['RName', 'RIn', 'SIn', 'OIn']}]
Traceback (most recent call last):

line 127, in main
    client.write_points(json.dumps(json_body))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 173, in write_points
    return self.write_points_with_precision(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 197, in write_points_with_precision
    status_code=200
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 127, in request
    raise error
influxdb.client.InfluxDBClientError
```

I have tried with double quotes too but get the same error. This is stub code (to minimize the solution), I realize in the example the points list contains just one list object but in reality it contains multiple. I am generating the JSON code reading through outputs of various API calls.

```
json_body = '[{\"points\":['
json_body += '[\"appx\", 1, 10, 0]'
json_body += '], \"name\": \"WS1\", \"columns\": [\"RName\", \"RIn\", \"SIn\", \"OIn\"]}]'

print("Write points: {0}".format(json_body))
client.write_points(json.dumps(json_body))
```

I understand if I used the below things would work:

```
json_body = [{ "points": [["appx", 1, 10, 0]], "name": "WS1", "columns": ["Rname", "RIn", "SIn", "OIn"]}]
```

Comment: Uhh... why are you attempting to generate it manually? Especially since you're getting it completely wrong?

Comment: Thank you sir. Can you help me understand how to get it right? Like mentioned I can get it right by creating the json_obj directly but thats not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create JSON manually. Just pass an appropriate Python structure into `write_points` function. Try something like that:

```
data = [{'points':[['appx', 1, 10, 0]],
         'name': 'WS1',
         'columns': ['RName', 'RIn', 'SIn', 'OIn']}]

client.write_points(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please visit [JSON.org](http://json.org) for proper JSON structure. I can see several errors with your self-generated JSON:

1. The outer-most item can be an unordered object, enclosed by curly braces `{}`, or an ordered array, enclosed by brackets `[]`. Don't use both. Since your data is structured like a dict, the curly braces are appropriate.
2. All strings need to be enclosed in **double** quotes, not single. `"This is valid JSON"`. `'This is not valid'`.
3. Your `'points'` value array is surrounded by double brackets, which is unnecessary. Only use a single set.

Please check out the [documentation of the `json` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) for details on how to use it. Basically, you can feed `json.dumps()` your Python data structure, and it will output it as valid JSON.

```
In [1]: my_data = {'points': ["appx", 1, 10, 0], 'name': "WS1", 'columns': ["RName", "RIn", "SIn", "OIn"]}

In [2]: my_data
Out[2]: {'points': ['appx', 1, 10, 0], 'name': 'WS1', 'columns': ['RName', 'RIn', 'SIn', 'OIn']}

In [3]: import json

In [4]: json.dumps(my_data)
Out[4]: '{"points": ["appx", 1, 10, 0], "name": "WS1", "columns": ["RName", "RIn", "SIn", "OIn"]}'
```

You'll notice the value of using a Python data structure first: because it's Python, you don't need to worry about single vs. double quotes, `json.dumps()` will automatically convert them. However, building a string with embedded single quotes leads to this:

```
In [5]: op_json = "[{'points':[['appx', 1, 10, 0]], 'name': 'WS1', 'columns': ['RName', 'RIn', 'SIn', 'OIn']}]"

In [6]: json.dumps(op_json)
Out[6]: '"[{\'points\':[[\'appx\', 1, 10, 0]], \'name\': \'WS1\', \'columns\': [\'RName\', \'RIn\', \'SIn\', \'OIn\']}]"'
```

since you fed the **string** to `json.dumps()`, not the **data structure**.

So next time, don't attempt to build JSON yourself, rely on the dedicated module to do it.

Comment: 1. A list containing one object is not wrong. So [{"x": "Y"}] is not an error. This is example code in reality I have Multiple objects in the list etc but I have tried to minimize the problem. 2. I have tried double quotes as well as single quotes but get the same issue. 3. Same point about points value. As I have lots of points to write I was planning to create one JSON structure and then call the write_points, but for now I will just write points one at a time. Thanks all for your help.